# Adding a body ID to a view page

Tags: views

I would like to add a body id to a view page in Drupal 6 - would I modify template.php? I'm trying to figure out where to make the correct modification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in a couple ways.

Easiest, if you have only one Views page that needs this, you could go into your theme's directory and copy `page.tpl.php` to `page-PATHTOVIEWPAGE.tpl.php` and then inside there, put in the id, eg,

```
<body id="ID" ... >
```

Just change any `/`s in your path to this page to `-`s in the template name and you should be all set.  Take a peek at [Drupal 6 Template Suggestions](https://drupal.org/node/1089642) for more info.

Now, if you are going to want to do this in multiple pages or need it to be more extensible, then, yes, you will most probably want to add in a `preprocess_page()` hook in `template.php` as well as another custom `page.tpl.php` template file.

What you could do would be to copy `page.tpl.php` inside your theme to, let's say `page-with-body-id.tpl.php`.  Then, inside there, you could put something like this:

```
<body id="<?php print $body_id; ?>" ... >
```

Then, inside `template.php` you would add in a `preprocess_page()` hook, eg, something like this:

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {

   $whereami=$_GET['q'];  // eg, www.yourhost.com/WHEREAMI

   switch ($whereami) {

     case 'events':
     case 'news':
     case 'press':

       $variables['body_id']=$whereami;
       $variables['template_files'][]='page-with-body-id'; // and use this new template

       break;

    }

    // any other page preprocessing goes here

 }
```

Just make sure you don't create a page template that would match an existing path on your system.  I doubt `www.yoursite.com/with/body/id` exists but you never know :)

Otherwise, another good place to look for info is here: [Overriding Theme Templates in Drupal 6](https://drupal.org/node/337022).

Also, if you can use a body class instead of an id, this is even simpler:

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {

   $whereami=$_GET['q'];  // eg, www.yourhost.com/WHEREAMI

   switch ($whereami) {

     case 'events':
     case 'news':
     case 'press':

       if (empty($variables['body_classes'])) { 
         $variables['body_classes']='view-' . $whereami;
       } else {
         $variables['body_classes'].=' view-' . $whereami;
       }

       break;

    }

    // any other page preprocessing goes here

 }
```

which will add `view-WHEREAMI` to the list of classes for the body in (most) default page templates.

RE: [How do I do an if conditional based on a view in template.php](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/96787/how-do-i-do-an-if-conditional-based-on-a-view-in-template-php), you can also do something like this in the appropriate spot:

```
$mgi=menu_get_item();

if ($mgi['page_callback']=='views_page' && $mgi['page_arguments'][0]=='WHATVIEWYOUARELOOKINGFOR') {

  // you are on the views page you are looking for

}
```

Comment: Yes, I need more information there. I'm not sure how to use preprocess_page() to add this in.

Comment: So either way I want to do it, I have to have a whole new page.tpl file for every single view?

Comment: no, you can put logic inside your preprocess to allow for multiple page templates just like how page.tpl.php is used for multiple ones.

Comment: I'm not following. So let's say I have a view with the name events, another view with the name news, and another view with the name press - I could use the same template file - say page-for-views.tpl.php, and use only one preprocess command in the template.php file? Am I reading you correctly on that? Sorry for my lack of understanding on this.

Comment: I've add some more specifics to my code example

Comment: I'm trying to point it to $variables['template_files'][]='page_header'; - which is apparently where the code for the header (and the body id) is. It does not appear when I'm echoing the body id out.

Comment: doing that will cause it to look for a file called `page_header.tpl.php`.  is that what you want? I've not seen a `<body>` tag in any header templates before. what theme are you actually using?

Comment: No, the file name is page_header.php. My impression is that this PHP file was written before anyone at the company had any knowledge of proper Drupal construction - it's a legacy build.

Comment: well I don't know how any of this is working if it is actually called `page_header.php` without the `.tpl.` in there.  But regardless, if you want to have an id or class added to the body tag of a certain page, you have to point drupal to it in any of the manners described above.  you just need to find the appropriate file that is working on your site and copy it to a filename described above and add in the php code to add in the id or class.

Comment: Is there anyway to check if a page that is currently loaded has a given view? Is that possible? That might be another workaround for my problem.

Comment: Sure, just somewhere in the template file you think is being used, print out what is returned from `menu_get_item()` as mentioned here and in your other question and it will tell you how the page has been created.

Comment: Yep, think I've got it. Hackish, but sadly I think that's the best solution here today.