# How do I do an if conditional based on a view in template.php

Tags: views

Related to this question: [Adding a body ID to a view page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/96780/adding-a-body-id-to-a-view-page/96781?noredirect=1#96781)

How do I add a conditional based on whether a page is a view or not? I'm not sure how to test for whether a page is a view.

Comment: If you can avoid - don't. If you have to, investigate [`views_get_view`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_get_view/7).

Comment: Sadly, I cannot avoid it. The project lead has more or less said no additional modules will be used.

Comment: Well, that's pretty much a questionable approach that leads to dirty hacks instead of cleanly written custom modules, but oh well. I don't have time now to give you an answer, I hope my hint above will help.

Comment: Yes, that sounds par for the course for this operation. I hope someone else will be able to assist, given my constraints.

Answer (score 0):

You can call [menu_get_item()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_get_item/6) and it will return an array containing a lot of information about the path you are on.

Inside that, you can look for

```
[page_callback] => views_page
[page_arguments] => Array (
  [0] => arg0
  [1] => arg1
)
```

or similar, and then based upon that, figure out what View you are looking at.

FYI:  It might not be obvious from the documentation, but if you call it without arguments, it returns the information about the path/page you are currently on.